# Unable to combine standard and custom object using SOQL?

Tags: soql

I got two queries fetching data from separate objects.  As Im a beginner in SOQL , I find it hard to combine these queries and get the data.

Query 1

```
select  opportunity.name, (select UnitPrice from OpportunityLineItems) from opportunity
```

Query 2

```
select  Revenue__c from  Opportunity_Line_Item_Detail__c
```

Some more info about the parent-child (attaching the creenshot):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tried to combine the two queries:

```
SELECT Name,
    (SELECT UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItems) ,
    (SELECT Revenue__c FROM Opportunity_Line_Item_Details__r) 
    FROM opportunity
```

Its done using [Left Outer Join](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com), where in you have to use child relationship name while specifying the object.

Comment: @lijindevkeloth If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.